# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') openai:v3.2.1 discord.js: 14.9.0

Tags: node.js, discord.js, openai-api

i keep getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')" in shell, here is my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const openai = require('openai');

openai.apiKey = 'i put my api key here';

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ama')
    .setDescription('ask me anything!')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('prompt')
        .setDescription('type any question...')),

  async execute(interaction) {
    try {
      const prompt = interaction.options.getString('prompt');

      const gptResponse = await openai.Completion.create({
        engine: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: `answer the following question that is asked.\n\
      ChatGPT: Hello, how are you?\n\
      ${interaction.user.username}: ${prompt}\n\
      ChatGPT:`,
        temperature: 0,
        max_tokens: 100,
        stop: ["human:", "AI:", "Rayyan"],
      });
      interaction.reply(`${gptResponse.choices[0].text}`);
      return;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
};
```

expecting for the discord bot to repond with the correct answer to my question when i do the slash command in discord